# Tabs at tablet in android

Tags: android, tabs, viewpage

I have a problem in one of my apps. I have a viewpage with two tabs that show different content. In my phone this tabs habe the full width of the phone. But in tablet the are a black space at both side of the screen. In the example you can see what i am talking about. Any help?
Thx in advance.

[Tablet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzZ8k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for all! I solve it using in activityMain.java onCreate method.

```
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.bluedark)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use center gravity in your app tab layout, if the case replace  app:tabGravity=”center”  to app:tabGravity=”fill” in your tab Layout

Comment: I tried this, changing styles.xml and it didn't work :(... Thx for the help Abdel.

Comment: Are your tried to set your tabLayout width to match_parent?